# Python, ImportError: cannot import name AbstractLazySequence

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

I am using nltk but the problem I am facing does not seem to be related to nltk specifically. 
I have a module named `util.tokenize` inside which there are some classes and I have the following first line:

util/tokenizer.py

```
from nltk.tokenize.regexp import RegexpTokenizer
...

class SentTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self, stem=False, pattern='[^\w\-\']+'):
        self.alg = RegexpTokenizer(pattern, gaps=True)

    def __call__(self, text):
        return self.alg.tokenize(text)
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
     s_t = SentTokenizer()
     s_t('blah blah')
```

When I call those classes from another module, say `test.py` everything seems to work, but running the `tokenize.py` module directly causes ImportError.

```
File "tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
...      
File "Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 28, in <module>
        from nltk.util import AbstractLazySequence, LazySubsequence, LazyConcatenation, py25
    ImportError: cannot import name AbstractLazySequence
```

What could be the problem? Why it works when called from other modules?

test.py

```
from util.tokenize import SentTokenizer
s_t = SentTokenizer()
print s_t('blah blah')
```

Platform is Windows.

Comment: Added more parts of the relevant code

Comment: It does not even get to the __main__ code. At line one it throws error. 
I added more code. @grill

Comment: What happens if you create a new .py file with just the code you included above (excluding ellipses)?

Comment: I copied the same exact code to a new module outside the ``util`` package and I can run it directly without problems. But the original module (``tokenize.py``) which is inside the ``util`` package, throws exception. 
So my guess is it is related to package naming.

Comment: Try naming the package something different and see what happens. I smell a namespace conflict...

Comment: Renamed it to ``blah``. Same error. @grill

Comment: I'm working on this question as well.  I suggest moving it to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78241/temp-room)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We determined that this was being caused by a namespace conflict with `nltk.tokenize` and the user's `tokenize.py`. After renaming `tokenize.py`, everything worked properly.